# Is it possible to change the default value of an attribute before adding to core data using textfield?

Tags: cocoa, attributes

I have my core data shown in a NSTableView. I want to be able to use user inputs (NSTextFields) to populate the next row when the user clicks add.

My current approach is to try to use a manager object to collect the string value from the text field and then make that the default for the next core data addition.

for some reason after I alloc and init the textfield I cant use the value (it shows up as blank in my table) (not null).

Can you please advise? Thank you in advance:

```
//this is my core data object
//  ItemEntity.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ItemEntity : NSManagedObject{
}
-(NSString *) titleValue;
@end



//  ItemEntity.m
#import "ItemEntity.h"
#import "MyManager.h"

@implementation ItemEntity


-(NSString *)titleValue{
    MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
    NSString *nam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sharedManager.titleText]; //titleText from MyManager;
    return nam;

}
@end



//  MyManager.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    @private
    IBOutlet NSTextField *titleLabel;
    NSString *titleText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titleText;
+ (id)sharedManager;
@end


//  MyManager.m
#import "MyManager.h"
@implementation MyManager
@synthesize titleText;

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        titleLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] init];

        NSString *myString = [titleLabel stringValue];

        titleText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"default, %@", myString];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

titleLabel links to the input NSTextField

titleText is a singleton that passes the string to ItemEntity

titleValue is the model key path in core data

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do following steps:

1)Create New project using core data

2)you will find CoreDataExample.xcdatamodelid, click on that.

3)select entity and click on Add Entity, this option will be in bottom.

4)select Entities and add attribute and set type as string

5)go to mainmenu.xib drag table view, text field and two buttons "+" and "-".

make tableview non editable

5)drag one array controller in main menu.xib,select arraycontroller go to Attribute inspector

make the changes in following parameter

Mode - Entity Name

Entity Name - label (whatever you have given in "CoreDataExample.xcdatamodelid")

check two checkbox - prepare and Editable

6)select table column bind to ArrayController, controller key:arrangedObjects

modelKeypath:titleValue

select Textfield bind to ArrayController, controller key:selection modelKeypath:titleValue

8)connect + button to ArrayController's add action, Connect - button to ArrayController's

remove action.

9)launch the application, cick on add button, row will be add to table view, start typing in

text field, tab out and see table view will populate with same thing